# No laziness in some vector operation

Tags: haskell

This code tries to eagerly evaluate `[1..]` which causes an infinite loop.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

infiniteLoop = V.zipWith (+) (V.fromList [1..4]) (V.fromList [1..])
```

Why is this so?

Comment: A vector needs to know its size. Unlike a list, a vector cannot be built and grown gradually as data comes in. I'm not sure how Monad comes into play here.

Comment: you should make this an answer @n.m.

Comment: @n.m. Vector is a Stream, which seems to hold a Monadic value. Tracing the source code of `Data.Vector.fromList` leads you to this original definition of `fromList` from module [`Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.4/docs/src/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream-Monadic.html#fromList)

Comment: `fromList` builds a vector from a stream which is built from a list. Vector itself is not a stream.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last sentence of the question. The list type, `[]`, is a monad and you can make infinite lists.

Comment: `vector`s are finite-size due to being more strict than lists. Once you know that you have a vector, you know its size. For lists, you only know that you have a list. Streams come into play due to rewriting rules. I'll point to the original paper in my answer, which is fairly accessible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compile with `-O2`.

... ok this only works in certain cases.

In your `unoptimised` build, the two vectors created via `fromList` are built first. Since vectors are spine-strict (and unboxed ones hyperstrict), this will fail as you can not construct an infinite-size vector.

If you compile with `-O2`, `stream fusion` comes into play. Now, all intermediate vectors (the ones from `fromList`) are not created at all. Since `zipWith` stops once the first supply of data is done, you now have a terminating function.

But in general: don't use infinite-size supplies with vector operations, the semantics of your functions now depend on your optimization level, which is bad.

The original ["stream fusion" paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1291199) describes the switch from lists to streams, and back to lists again. For simplification you can think of lists as vectors (as vectors add a bunch of additional stuff like memory allocation, monadic behaviour, ...).

In general (and much simplified), rewriting rules are used to internally represent vectors as streams, enabling fusion, and streams are then turned back into vectors.

Comment: This is (perhaps unfortunately) the correct answer. In this particular case, the stream fusion `Vector` uses is able to get rid of the infinite list. But there are two caveats. One, you must compile with optimizations for stream fusion to happen. Two, it's fragile, in that stream fusion sometimes doesn't trigger even with optimizations on. As @choener says, you shouldn't make the semantics of your program depend on an optimization working.

Comment: I believe the vector package exposes the stream processing machinery more directly in a different module.

Answer (score 5):

Data.Vector.fromList is [documented](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html) to take O(N) time. Here, you've supplied an infinite number of items, so it takes infinite time to complete.

As for why vectors can't be constructed lazily: they promise good performance for other operations (take, drop, length, indexing...), which requires using a data structure that knows how many elements exist.

Comment: I don't see how the asymptotic complexity of the operation comes into place. Sure the *complete evaluation* of `fromList` takes O(n) time, but so does a complete evaluation of `map`, yet `take 10 $ map f [1..]` doesn't take infinite time, since the evaluation is lazy.